# How would I use the same SessionHandler for different Handlers in jetty 9 embedded?

Tags: session, jetty, handler

Is there a way in jetty to have 2 different context handlers pointing to 2 different handlers but using the same sessionhandler? Or is it somehow possible to share the session cache between two different session handlers?

```
/myapp/ -> static content (form login is shown) 
/rest/ -> api for rest calls from javascript
```

Comment: Are those 2 different contexts? aka two different ServletContext?

Comment: Yes, to distinguish between the app resources (static files like js, css, ..) and the rest api I use /myapp/ for the app and /rest/ for rest calls. Or should I use the same context and somehow decide if its a rest call or not?

Comment: It's generally not supported to have the same Session between multiple ServletContext's, as it different classloaders with different class instances which will trigger a number of low level JVM exceptions when you attempt it.  There are workarounds, but it requires not using features of the Servlet spec.  It's actually easier to just have 1 ServletContext and properly defined url-patterns.

Comment: I was trying to use a ServletWrapper which forwards to one of my ServletHandlers depending on the context path but didn't get it to work. So in the end I'm now using different ServletContexts, all using SqlSessionHandlers pointing to the same database table. This seems to work now.
Thank you for the clarification. I was unsure if sharing a Session was supported or not.